# Connection Not Enstablished - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, routes, rubygems

I'm totally new to **Ruby on Rails** and I'm giving it a shot. 
I'm saying in advance that I didn't find an answer to fit my problem nor here on StackOverflow nor on the internet (I tried lots of different things picked from SO and other web sites).

I'm following **Rails for Zombies 2** on **CodeSchool** and I need to set up the enviroment in order to make things happen.

In order to make that, I'm following the setup phase from **Michael Hartl's
Ruby on Rails Tutorial.**

I followed every step but, when I would love to see: *"hello, world!*" in my browser I get:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base
```

**Full trace:**

```
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:566:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
```

Before getting this, I installed Rails, I entered my hello_app folder and used: Bundle Install and then I just used: Rails Server. I also deleted index.html as said in the guide.

**My Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '>= 3.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry-byebug', platform: [:ruby_20]
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end
```

**My Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception

      def hello
        render text: "hello, world!"
      end
end
```

**My Routes:**

```
HelloApp::Application.routes.draw do
        root 'application#hello
end
```

**My Database:**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I'm sorry if my problem is trivial and I'm also sorry for my awful english.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. It was a problem cause by a broken Gemfile.
The right configuration that allowed me to let it work is:

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported     runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.   Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

 group :development, :test do
# Call 'debugger' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'debugger'

# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
   gem 'spring'
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

BTW, have you run the `bundle exec rake db:setup` before starting the server? It looks like if your database just doesn't exist yet (you can check whether the `db/development.sqlite3` file exists).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but running `bundle exec rake db: setup` doesn't work, I get the same thing as before. **db/development.sqlite3** does exist but it is empty. Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't work or does nothing? And it is `db:setup` (no spaces inside). Also try `rake db:create`.

Comment: Also the file shouldn't be empty — you should be able to open it using some sqlite editor, e.g. http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: Yes I wrote `db:setup` correctly. `rake db:create` gives me: `db/development.sqlite3 already exists
 db/test.sqlite3 already exists` .

Comment: Does running `rails console` and calling `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` from it fails too?

Comment: Running `rails console` gives [this](http://imgur.com/Aw5xQOD). Anyways, maybe it is a problem caused by a broken installation? Should I remove everything and doing it from the very beginning?

Comment: You can check whether your ruby/rails installation work using something like `rails new blog; cd blog; rails server`. But I believe something is just messed up in that tutorial configs.

Comment: And btw, as I see you are using quite old ruby version (1.9.1), you'll better install something newer like 2.2.3, it can solve lots of issues.

Comment: I solved it, changed my gemfile. Thanks anyways for the help.